# Software to monitor Windows API calls on a Windows 7

Tags: windows, monitoring

I want to monitor all calls to the Windows API.

So just to make clear, this would be software that can log/display the API calls made by windowed applications and background services running on a standalone Windows system.

Should preferably be open source, but proprietary software is also OK (I don't want to indicate a max price I am willing to pay as that is open based on if the software has any other functionality).

Would be great if the application was compatible with Windows 10 as well.

Comment: Are you asking about the Windows API, or do you also want to monitor calls to popular third-party DLLs, or even to any random DLL that people might create?

Comment: Hi @NicolasRaoul, I meant any and all API calls (I thought that they could all be monitored through some common mechanism but maybe I am wrong)

Comment: Including even HTTP API and Java API calls for instance?

Answer (score 4):

I have always used [API Monitor from Rohitab](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor). Not only does it do what you want but it also has other functions.

It supports Windows 7, including x64. Windows 10 is not (yet) listed as a supported OS (statements from the main page):

> Windows 2000, Windows XP 32-bit, Windows XP 64-bit x64, Windows Vista 32-bit, Windows Vista 64-bit x64, Windows 7 32-bit, Windows 7 64-bit x64, Windows 8 32-bit, Windows 8 64-bit x64
>
> The 64-bit version can only be used to monitor 64-bit applications and the 32-bit version can be only be used to monitor 32-bit applications. To monitor a 32-bit application on 64-bit Windows, you must use the 32-bit version. Note that the 64-bit installer for API Monitor includes both 64-bit and 32-bit versions.

It supports monitoring services (statements from the main page):

> API Monitor supports monitoring of 64-bit applications and services.

It is not open source, but available gratis. The license text is not online but displayed during installation and says:

> rohitab.com grants you the right to install and use copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT on your computer running a validly licensed copy of the operating system for which the SOFTWARE PRODUCT was designed.
>
> All title, including but not limited to copyrights, in and to the SOFTWARE PRODUCT and any copies thereof are owned by rohitab.com or its suppliers.

Answer (score 3):

I'll recommend you **[Nektra SpyStudio](http://www.nektra.com/products/spystudio-api-monitor/)**, it can trace Windows API calls and 3rd party calls as seen in the image below. It works great on any Windows, however, I never noticed whether it can trace services.

[image]

### Trace Application

> SpyStudio shows and interprets calls, displaying the results in a
>   structured way which is easy for any IT professional to understand.
>   SpyStudio can show registry keys and files that an application uses,
>   COM objects and Windows the application has created, and errors and
>   exceptions

### Process Monitor Complement

> SpyStudio is the user-mode Procmon complement. Looking for application
>   errors with kernel-mode traces is tedious, and it is very difficult to
>   see the final outcome of a user-mode call. With kernel-mode tools, you
>   get a lot of noise that the application does not see, since a single
>   user-mode call generates lots of kernel-mode events that are not
>   important from the application's perspective. Most application errors
>   are generated by failed user-mode calls which expect a different state
>   of some resources: registry keys and values, files, pipes, services
>   and printers.
>
> SpyStudio is also able to read Process Monitor logs (see Load ProcMon
>   log) and show them in a user friendly interface. It shows registry
>   operations in tree form like Regedit and displays errors in red. File
>   operations are also displayed in tree form.

Comment: The website is not really verbose about the license. Is it free or just a trial?

Comment: @Thomas it is trial, seems very hard to find a free applicaton for this task that meets the requisites, because needs a lot of effort from the programmer to consider develop it for free.